# Can compile file but can't find main class when trying to execute

Tags: java, windows, apache-poi, command-prompt

I am currently trying to work with xls files with java and had following problem.
I can compile my code via cmd:
`javac -cp poi-4.0.1.jar;poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar pdatexls.java`

No problems there, but trying to execute the file with:
`java -cp poi-4.0.1.jar;poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar updatexls`

gives me:

> Error: Mainclass updatexls couldn't be found or loaded

I have the .jar files in a folder together with the `updatexls.java` and `updatexls.class`. I am only using this for some small programs, so I don't want to use any kind of JDE.

It seems like setting the classpath with `-cp` for my .jar files is kind of the problem? Because when I only try to use:
`java updatexls`

Java definitely finds the class but then I get loads of missing library missing errors of course. Running java files which don't need any library work fine too.
All I did to get java and javac working was setting the path with:
`set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin"`

```
import java.io.*;    
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;    
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;    
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;    
import java.util.Iterator;    

public class updatexls {      
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{    

            FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.xls"));

            HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document);     

            HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);    

            Cell cell = null;     

            cell = my_worksheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);    

            cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue() + 5);    

            input_document.close();    

            FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.xls"));    

            my_xls_workbook.write(output_file);    

            output_file.close();                
    }    
}
```

How can I get this running?

Comment: Add the current folder to the classpath too?

Comment: if you solved this , please answer your question with the solution and accept it to help other users with the same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java -cp poi-4.0.1.jar;poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar;. updatexls seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem one time.
What I did was:

1. Search for enviroment variables in your system, how:

[image]

2. Click on button 'enviroment variables', like:

[image]

3. Then in 'enviroment of system', click in 'new':

[image]

4. Put `JAVA_HOME` in the name field, in the next field put the path of your jdk. in my case was:

[image: image of creation of the new variable]

5. Click 'ok' and try to execute again.

Comment: Tried that and restarted, sadly didn't help